no output when run train command in juputer notebook
when i write this command in jupyter notebook
!python -m spacy train C:/Users/Asiana/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python312/Scripts/python_project1/modell/config.cfg --output ./output --paths.train C:/Users/Asiana/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python312/Scripts/python_project1/modell/train_data.spacy --paths.dev C:/Users/Asiana/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python312/Scripts/python_project1/modell/test_data.spacy --gpu-id 0 --verbose


i don't have any output
try write this command in the cmd i have the same problem

please add a focused, answerable question to your post
